# Draw a triangle with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Write a C++ program which will draw a triangle having vertices at (300,210),
(340,215) and (320,250). Center of the triangle lies at (320,240).

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(1,1,0,0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glColor3f(0.5,0,0);

    glVertex2f(300.0,210.0);
    glVertex2f(340.0,215.0);
    glVertex2f(320.0,250.0);

    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(1,1);

    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Issue triangle isn't appearing only a yellow screen appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program needs an appropriate view/projection matrix. `glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, -1, 1)` should do the trick. Ideally it should be called with `MatrixMode` set to `GL_PROJECTION`.

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0,-1, 1);

    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0,400,0,500);

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate system in OpenGL is from -1 -> 1. You'll have to convert your coordinates from your desired pixel values.

This can be done by some linear interpolation. Something like this should work:

```
float c = -1.0 + 2.0*desiredPixel/pixelWidth
```

You would need to do this conversion for all your triangle coordinates.

Comment: that is inefficient

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple and valid triangle code:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f(0.1, 0.2, 0.3);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
glEnd();
```

Comment: i switched to glvertex2i and used the  'glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0,400,0,500);'

Answer (score 1):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D(0,400,0,500);
```

This solved my issue mostly 3D perspective was not working i think